# sentiment analysis on product reviews

Tags: java, classification, sentiment-analysis, review

I am doing sentiment analysis on the product reviews using SentiWordNet. But it shows some positive words like "not bad" etc as positive and also a wrong score is genertated. Most of the time score returned goes beyond -1 and 1.
The code i used is posting here. please see this:

```
    package scoreget;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class SWN3 {
    private String pathToSWN = "E:\\proj\\SentiWordNet_3.0.0.1.txt";
    private HashMap<String, Double> _dict;

    public SWN3(){

        _dict = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        HashMap<String, Vector<Double>> _temp = new HashMap<String, Vector<Double>>();
        try{
            BufferedReader csv =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToSWN));
            String line = "";           
            while((line = csv.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] data = line.split("\t");
                Double score = Double.parseDouble(data[2])-Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
                String[] words = data[4].split(" ");
                for(String w:words)
                {
                    String[] w_n = w.split("#");
                    w_n[0] += "#"+data[0];
                    int index = Integer.parseInt(w_n[1])-1;
                    if(_temp.containsKey(w_n[0]))
                    {
                        Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(w_n[0]);
                        if(index>v.size())
                            for(int i = v.size();i<index; i++)
                                v.add(0.0);
                        v.add(index, score);
                        _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Vector<Double> v = new Vector<Double>();
                        for(int i = 0;i<index; i++)
                            v.add(0.0);
                        v.add(index, score);
                        _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                    }
                }
            }
            Set<String> temp = _temp.keySet();
            for (Iterator<String> iterator = temp.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                String word = (String) iterator.next();
                Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(word);
                double score = 0.0;
                double sum = 0.0;
                for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
                    score += ((double)1/(double)(i+1))*v.get(i);
                for(int i = 1; i<=v.size(); i++)
                    sum += (double)1/(double)i;
                score /= sum;
                String sent = "";               
                if(score>=0.75)
                    sent = "strong_positive";
                else
                if(score > 0.25 && score<=0.5)
                    sent = "positive";
                else
                if(score > 0 && score>=0.25)
                    sent = "weak_positive";
                else
                if(score < 0 && score>=-0.25)
                    sent = "weak_negative";
                else
                if(score < -0.25 && score>=-0.5)
                    sent = "negative";
                else
                if(score<=-0.75)
                    sent = "strong_negative";
                _dict.put(word, score); 

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}        
    }

   public Double extract(String word)
    {
      Double total = new Double(0);
      if(_dict.get(word+"#n") != null)
      total = _dict.get(word+"#n") + total;
      if(_dict.get(word+"#a") != null)
      total = _dict.get(word+"#a") + total;
      if(_dict.get(word+"#r") != null)
      total = _dict.get(word+"#r") + total;
      if(_dict.get(word+"#v") != null)
      total = _dict.get(word+"#v") + total;
    return total;
   }

      public static void connect(int p_id, String desc, Double score,String T_nam) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
       {
       try {

             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root", "");

              String sql="insert  into "+T_nam+"(p_id,Description,Score) values(?,?,?)";
              PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
              pst.setInt(1,p_id);

             pst.setString(2, desc);

           pst.setDouble(3, score);
              pst.executeUpdate(); 

             }
             catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();}
          }
         public static String calcscore(String p_id,String desc) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
     {
       SWN3 test = new SWN3();
        int pid=Integer.parseInt(p_id);
        String sentence=desc;
        String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+"); 
        double totalScore = 0;
        for(String word : words) {
        word = word.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z\\s])", "");
        if (test.extract(word) == null)
        continue;
        totalScore =test.extract(word)+totalScore;
      }
      connect(pid,sentence,totalScore,"review");

      return (Double.toString(totalScore));


     }
     public Double extract(String word, String pos)
     {
      return _dict.get(word+"#"+pos);
     }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    SWN3 obj=new SWN3();

      }
   }
```

Comment: Can you post some example output?

Comment: I delved further into this out of curiosity about [SentiWordNet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/) and found out that your code actually does not do what you describe: All it does it read in the file. If you want some help, you'll have to do more than just paste some random code into a question.